# Ruby IRB - Can't do Process.getrlimit

Tags: ruby, process, irb

I am reading a book "Working with Unix Processes" which uses ruby to explain about unix/linux processes. This is my first time working with ruby.  I tried an example to get resource limits on processes.

```
irb(main):001:0> Process.getrlimit(:CORE)
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - getrlimit
    from (irb):1:in `getrlimit'
    from (irb):1
    from :0


irb(main):004:0> Process.getrlimit()
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from (irb):4:in `getrlimit'
    from (irb):4
    from :0
```

But I can't seem to get "getrlimit" recognized  (though it says I have wrong number of arguments if I don't supply any args).  Haven't found anything on this on google or SO. Tried with :NOFILE, :CORE and others.  Is there something I need to include/require to make getrlimit work.  Environment:

```
Ubuntu 11.04 32 bit. Kernel 3.0.0-14
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry .. never mind.  It seems that IRB was running a previous version of ruby (1.8.7) which somehow didn't support the getrlimit (though according to all accounts on google, it should have worked).  I had upgraded ruby to 1.9.1 but did not update the link from /usr/bin/irb to /usr/bin/irb1.9.1.  So IRB was still running ruby 1.8.7.  After updating the softlink of irb to v1.9.1,  getrlimit is now working.

Comment: Consider using a version manager such as RVM (http://rvm.io) or rbenv (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) when installing multiple Ruby versions. It's not recommended to change the system's native installation.

Comment: For Ruby 1.8 the correct syntax is `Process.getrlimit(Process::RLIMIT_CORE)`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @Casper. Ruby 1.9 allowed for symbols as shortcuts for longer constant names in a bunch of places: https://gist.github.com/3254777.